# How to generate the proper indices in srcbook using imakeidx and splitindex?

Tags: scrbook, imakeidx, splitindex

I have a MWE generated of my book with lipsum. this compiles smoothly, but does not generate the four indices as desired. What do I miss?

````
\documentclass[ngerman,12pt,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[%
paperheight=297mm, paperwidth=210mm%
]{geometry}
\usepackage[]{lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{Alegreya}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem,longtable,caption,tabularx,xcolor,multirow}
\usepackage[splitindex]{imakeidx}
\usepackage{xparse, setspace}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\setkomafont{descriptionlabel}{\normalfont  \bfseries}
\newcommand{\leer}{\relax}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcommand{\tcg}[1]{\textcolor{gray}{#1}}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textsemibold}{\AlegreyaMedium}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textblack}{\AlegreyaBlack}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textextrabold}{\AlegreyaExtraBold}
\newcommand{\RRar}{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}
\newcommand{\ScN}[1]{\textsemibold{\textit{#1}}}%Scientic Names
\newcommand{\BTS}[2]{\ScN{#1 #2\index[sci]{#1!#2|boldhyperpage}\index[sci]{#2}}} %Index Scientific wenn mehrere Falter in einer Gattung
\newcommand{\BTSone}[2]{\ScN{#1 #2\index[sci]{#1 #2|boldhyperpage}\index[sci]{#2}}} %Index Scientific wenn ein Falter in einer Gattung
\newcommand{\bts}[2]{\index[sci]{#1!#2|boldhyperpage}\index[sci]{#2}}
\newcommand{\btsone}[2]{\index[sci]{#1 #2|boldhyperpage}\index[sci]{#2}}
\newcommand{\Bts}[1]{\ScN{#1 \index[sci]{#1|boldhyperpage}}} %Index Scientific wenn nur ein Falter aus der Gattung
\newcommand{\BTD}[1]{#1\index[dt]{#1|boldhyperpage}} %Index deutsch
\newcommand{\Btd}[1]{\index[dt]{#1|boldhyperpage}} %Index deutsch
\newcommand{\PFL}[3]{#1#2\index[pfl]{#2!#1!#3}\index[pflinv]{#3!#2!#1}}
\newcommand{\pfl}[3]{\index[pfl]{#2!#1!#3}\index[pflinv]{#3!#2!#1}} % für die unter "u.a." erwähnten
\usepackage{array}
\ExplSyntaxOn\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\subitem{\peek_meaning_ignore_spaces:NF\relax{\@idxitem \hspace*{20\p@}}}
\renewcommand*\subsubitem{\peek_meaning_ignore_spaces:NF\relax{\@idxitem \hspace*{40\p@}}}
\ExplSyntaxOff\makeatother
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2mm}
\makeindex[name=sci, title=Wissenschaftliche Namen, columns=3]
\makeindex[name=dt, title=Deutsche Namen]
\makeindex[name=pfl, title=Raupenwirtspflanzen (nach Pflanzen sortiert), columns=2]
\makeindex[name=pflinv, title= Raupenwirtspflanzen (nach Faltern sortiert), columns=3]
\usepackage[colorlinks=false, pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\DeclareDocumentCommand\mychapter{sO{#3}m}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}%
    %   {\chapter*{#3}\renewcommand*{\chapterthumbformat}{#3}}%
    %   {\chapter[{#2}]{#3}\renewcommand*{\chapterthumbformat}
        {\thechapter\enskip#2}}%
    %   }
\begin{document}    
    \newpage
\begin{longtable}{@{}p{5.8cm}@{}p{1cm}@{\hspace{3mm}}p{5.8cm}@{}p{1cm}@{}}%Argynni
    \multicolumn{4}{@{}p{10.8cm}@{}}{\large\textbf{Argynni -- Perlmutterfalter}}
    \\[2mm]
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{6cm}@{}}{\includegraphics[width=5.8cm]{example-image-duck}}
    &
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{6cm}@{}}{\includegraphics[width=5.8cm]{example-image-duck}}
    \\
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{5.3cm}@{}}{\BTD{Kaisermantel}} & \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{5.3cm}@{}}{\BTD{Großer Perlmutterfalter}} 
    \\
    \BTSone{Argynnis}{paphia}\label{argynnispaphia} & RL=*  & \BTSone{Speyeria}{aglaja}\label{speyeriaaglaja}  & RL=*
    \\
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{5.3cm}@{}}{\includegraphics[height=3mm]{example-image-a}}
    &
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{5.3cm}@{}}{\includegraphics[height=3mm]{example-image-a}} 
    \\
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{5.3cm}@{}}{Veilchen-Arten\pfl{\relax}{Veilchen}{Argynnis paphia}           
    } 
    & 
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{5.3cm}@{}}{Veilchen-Arten\pfl{Rauhaariges }{Veilchen}{Speyeria aglaja}\pfl{Hunds-}{Veilchen}{Speyeria aglaja}\pfl{Wald-}{Veilchen}{Speyeria aglaja}\pfl{Sumpf-}{Veilchen}{Speyeria aglaja}         
    }
    \\[1mm]
    
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{6cm}@{}}{\includegraphics[width=5.8cm]{example-image-duck}}
    &
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{6cm}@{}}{\includegraphics[width=5.8cm]{example-image-duck}}
    \\
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{5.3cm}@{}}{\BTD{Feuriger Perlmutterfalter}} & \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{5.3cm}@{}}{\BTD{Mittlerer Perlmutterfalter}} 
    \\
    \BTS{Fabriciana}{adippe}\label{fabricianaadippe} & \textbf{RL=V}  & \BTS{Fabriciana}{niobe}\label{fabriciananiobe}  & \textbf{RL=3}
    \\
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{5.3cm}@{}}{\includegraphics[height=3mm]{example-image-a}}
    &
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{5.3cm}@{}}{\includegraphics[height=3mm]{example-image-a}} 
    \\
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{5.3cm}@{}}{Veilchen-Arten\pfl{\relax}{Veilchen}{Fabriciana adippe}
    } 
    & 
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{5.3cm}@{}}{Veilchen-Arten\pfl{\relax}{Veilchen}{Fabriciana niobe}
    }            
    \\
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{6cm}@{}}{\includegraphics[width=5.8cm]{example-image-duck}}
    &
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{6cm}@{}}{\includegraphics[width=5.8cm]{example-image-duck}}
    \\
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{5.3cm}@{}}{\BTD{Kleiner Perlmutterfalter}} & \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{5.3cm}@{}}{\BTD{Natternwurz-Perlmutterfalter}} 
    \\
    \BTS{Issoria}{lathionia}\label{issorialathonia} & \textbf{RL=V}  & \BTS{Boloria}{titania}\label{boloriatitania} & \textbf{RL=3} 
    \\
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{5.3cm}@{}}{\includegraphics[height=3mm]{example-image-a}}
    &
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{5.3cm}@{}}{\includegraphics[height=3mm]{example-image-a}}
    \\
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{5.3cm}@{}}{\PFL{Acker-}{Stiefmütterchen}{Issoria lathonia}}  &
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{5.3cm}@{}}{\PFL{Wiesen-}{Knöterich}{Boloria titania}}
    \\[1mm]
    
\end{longtable}
\newpage
\begin{longtable}{@{}p{5.8cm}@{}p{1cm}@{\hspace{3mm}}p{5.8cm}@{}p{1cm}@{}}%Argynni
    \multicolumn{4}{@{}p{14cm}@{}}{\large\textbf{Argynni (2)}}
    \\[2mm]
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{6cm}@{}}{\includegraphics[width=5.2cm]{example-image-duck}}
    &
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{6cm}@{}}{\includegraphics[width=5.2cm]{example-image-duck}}
    \\
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{5.3cm}@{}}{\BTD{Hochmoor-Perlmutterfalter}} & \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{5.3cm}@{}}{\BTD{Silberfleck-Perlmutterfalter}} 
    \\
    \BTS{Boloria}{aquilonaris}\label{boloriaaquilonaris} & \textbf{RL=3}  & \BTS{Boloria}{euphrosyne}\label{boloriaeuphrosyne}  & \textbf{RL=V}
    \\
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{5.3cm}@{}}{\includegraphics[height=3mm]{example-image-a}}
    &
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{5.3cm}@{}}{\includegraphics[height=3mm]{example-image-a}} 
    \\
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{5.3cm}@{}}{\PFL{Gemeine }{Moosbeere}{Boloria aquilonaris}} 
    & 
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{5.3cm}@{}}{\PFL{\relax}{Veilchen}{Boloria euphrosyne}}
    \\[1mm]
    
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{6cm}@{}}{\includegraphics[width=5.2cm]{example-image-duck}}
    &
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{6cm}@{}}{\includegraphics[width=5.2cm]{example-image-duck}}
    \\
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{5.3cm}@{}}{\BTD{Randring-Perlmutterfalter}} & \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{5.8cm}@{}}{\BTD{Braunfleckiger Perlmutterfalter}} 
    \\
    \BTS{Boloria}{eunomia}\label{boloriaeunomia} & \textbf{RL=3}  & \BTS{Boloria}{selene}\label{boloriaselene}  & \textbf{RL=V}
    \\
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{5.3cm}@{}}{\includegraphics[height=3mm]{example-image-a}}
    &
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{5.3cm}@{}}{\includegraphics[height=3mm]{example-image-a}} 
    \\
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{5.3cm}@{}}{\PFL{Wiesen-}{Knöterich}{Boloria eunomia}} 
    & 
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{5.3cm}@{}}{\PFL{\relax}{Veilchen}{Boloria selene}}          
    \\[1mm]
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{6cm}@{}}{\includegraphics[width=5.3cm]{example-image-duck}}
    &
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{6cm}@{}}{\includegraphics[width=5.3cm]{example-image-duck}}
    \\
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{5.3cm}@{}}{\BTD{Mädesüß-Perlmutterfalter}} & \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{5.3cm}@{}}{\BTD{Magerrasen-Perlmutterfalter}} 
    \\
    \BTSone{Brenthis}{ino}\label{brenthisino} & \textbf{RL=V}  & \BTS{Boloria}{dia}\label{boloriadia}  & \textbf{RL=3}
    \\
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{5.3cm}@{}}{\includegraphics[height=3mm]{example-image-a}}
    &
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{5.3cm}@{}}{\includegraphics[height=3mm]{example-image-a}} 
    \\
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{5.3cm}@{}}{\PFL{\relax}{Mädesüß}{Brenthis ino} und \PFL{Großer }{Wiesenknopf}{Brenthis ino}} 
    & 
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{5.3cm}@{}}{\PFL{\relax}{Veilchen}{Boloria dia}}
    \\[1mm]
    
\end{longtable}

\part{Anhang}
\chapter[Index]{Stichwortverzeichnisse}
\footnotesize
\printindex[sci]
\printindex[dt]
\printindex[pfl]
\end{document}```
````

Comment: John Collins, author of latexmk evaluated the file and found some flaws. If this is solved I will add his comment . he is contacting also the author of the imakeidx package.

Comment: Which file? Your MWE?

Comment: I don't see real reasons to use `splitindex`. You lose the ability of specifying different formats for the individual indices.

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons that the indexes weren't made.

1. Specifically when imakeidx is invoked with the splitindex option, as in `\usepackage[splitindex]{imakeidx}`, latexmk doesn't currently detect the need for running makeindex.  This is unlike the case, for example, when the splitindex option is omitted, or when other packages are used for making the index(es).
2. In addition, with the splitindex option use, the splitindex program needs to be run to make the separate indexes.

The first problem is solved by adding the following line at the top of the document:

```
\typeout{Writing index file \jobname.idx}
```

This is the standard signature that latexmk uses for detecting the presence of an index.  (From v. 4.84, latexmk will improve its detection of index file creation, and this trick will not be needed.)

The second problem is solved by the following code in a latexmkrc file:

```
$makeindex = 'internal splitindex2 %S %D %R %B %O';
$clean_ext .= " %R-*.ind %R-*.idx %R-*.ilg %R-*.ind";

sub splitindex2 {
  # Use splitindex instead of makeindex.
  # The splitindex programe starts from an .idx file, makes a set of
  #   other .idx files for separate indexes, and then runs makeindex to
  #   make corresponding .ind files.
  # However, it is possible that the document uses the splitindex
  #   package, but in a way compatible with the standard methods
  #   compatible with makeindex, i.e., with a single index and with the
  #   use of the \printindex command.
  #   Then we need to invoke makeindex.
  # In addition, latexmk assumes that makeindex or its replacement makes
  #   an .ind file from an .idx file, and latexmk gives an error if it
  #   doesn't exist, so we need to make an .ind file.
  # Both problems are solved by running makeindex and then splitindex.
  # Note: errors are returned by makeindex and splitindex for things
  #   like a missing input file.  No error is returned for lines in an
  #   input file that are in an incorrect format; they are simply
  #   ignored.  So no problem is caused by lines in the .idx file
  #   that are generated by splitindex in a format incompatible with
  #   makeindex.
  my ($source, $dest, $root, $base, @opts) = @_;
  my $ret1 = system( "makeindex", $source );
  my $ret2 = system( "splitindex", $source );
  return $ret1 || $ret2;
}
```